Wahoo Kickr Core on a Campagnolo 11 Speed
I'm looking to purchase a Wahoo Kickr Core and was wondering at how compatible it is with other cassettes. I run Campagnolo 11 speed and my understanding is that it is fairly compatible with Shimano/SRAM/Sunrace etc.
Would I be safe buying a Kickr Core with a non-Campagnolo 11 speed cassette?

Yes, if you buy a Kickr Core with a Hyperglide freehub body, an 11s Shimano compatible cassette will work seamlessly with 11s Campy. I have been told that a 12s Shimano cassette will also work with 12s Campy. You can buy a Campy freehub for the trainer if you choose, at least for now.
Now, the Kickr Core Zwift One (listed on Zwift's site but not Wahoo's) has a single cog. It uses virtual shifting, changing the resistance on the software side. It's only compatible with Zwift, but it will allow anybody else in the household with basically an 8s or later drivetrain of any manufacturer to use the trainer. It is the same price, so it may be worth considering.
It's possible other indoor training software providers might adopt virtual shifting, but there's no word on this.
